# Android OpenGL 2.0 : Object Picking (seeing if you hit a object with a ray)

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

So I am trying to get object picking working in OpenGL 2, in OpenGK 1 I used the glpixelColor which was pretty straight forward.

I have the following code to give me the start and end point of my ray??

```
Log.i("My POSITION", "x:" + mRenderer.eye.x + " y:" + mRenderer.eye.y + " z:" + mRenderer.eye.z);

float xyzw[] = unproject(x, mRenderer.screenHeight - y, -1.0f);
Log.i("Start of ray", "x:" + xyzw[0] + " y:" + xyzw[1] + " z:" + xyzw[2]);

xyzw = unproject(x, mRenderer.screenHeight - y, 1.0f);
Log.i("End of Ray", "x:" + xyzw[0] + " y:" + xyzw[1] + " z:" + xyzw[2]);
```

I use the following function

```
public float[] unproject(float rx, float ry, float rz) {
            float[] xyzw = {0, 0, 0, 0};
            int[] viewport = { 0, 0, mRenderer.screenWidth, mRenderer.screenHeight};
            android.opengl.GLU.gluUnProject(rx, ry, rz, mRenderer.mViewMatrix, 0, mRenderer.mProjectionMatrix, 0, viewport, 0, xyzw, 0);
            xyzw[0] /= xyzw[3];
            xyzw[1] /= xyzw[3];
            xyzw[2] /= xyzw[3];
            xyzw[3] = 1;
            return xyzw;
        }
```

I get the following output

My POSITION: x:-1.857801 y:0.0 z:-8.655011
04-21

Start of ray: x:-1.8198236 y:-0.005848203 z:-8.688532
04-21

End of Ray: x:758.43915 y:-117.07846 z:-679.7136

**Question**
How do I work out if I have tapped on a cube at a position? Say the cube is at 1,1,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this and it kinda works

```
float xDif = (xyzw2[0] - xyzw[0]) / 1000;
float yDif = (xyzw2[1] - xyzw[1]) / 1000;
float zDif = (xyzw2[2] - xyzw[2]) / 1000;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++)
{
    if ((xyzw[0] + (xDif * i)) > mRenderer.cube.position.x - 1.0 && (xyzw[0] + (xDif * i)) < mRenderer.cube.position.x + 1.0 && 
        (xyzw[1] + (yDif * i)) > mRenderer.cube.position.y - 1.0 && (xyzw[1] + (yDif * i)) < mRenderer.cube.position.y + 1.0 &&
        (xyzw[2] + (zDif * i)) > mRenderer.cube.position.z - 1.0 && (xyzw[2] + (zDif * i)) < mRenderer.cube.position.z + 1.0)
        {   
        Log.i("Hit cube", "HIT");
        break;
        }
    }
```